# Command [[ error failed with status 1 org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException

Tags: pom.xml, maven-plugin, mojo

I connect to this other topic
[Why this error occur in compilation of my project on pom-xml tags indicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76810405/why-this-error-occur-in-compilation-of-my-project-on-pom-xml-tags-indicated)

and here I attach only the error code with details, can you help me understand what is causing it?

I'm trying to compile projects with maven, after having repeatedly checked the dependencies and successfully updated all projects

these errors come out on the pom.xml of the projects Command [[
here is the detail

```
Command [[
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java -Xmx512M -Xss1024k -
.... long class path here ...
]] failed with status 1 (com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:7.7.6:compile:default:process-classes)

org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Command [[
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java -Xmx512M -Xss1024k -
.... long class path here ...
C:\Users\myPC\.m2\repository\org\vaadin\addons\exporter\0.0.6\exporter-0.0.6.jar;
...
]] failed with status 1
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.compile(CompileMojo.java:582)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.doExecute(CompileMojo.java:435)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.AbstractGwtShellMojo.execute(AbstractGwtShellMojo.java:182)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.lambda$8(MavenImpl.java:1423)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1422)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.build(MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.java:55)
    at com.vaadin.integration.eclipse.maven.VaadinMojoExecutionBuildParticipant.build(VaadinMojoExecutionBuildParticipant.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.lambda$1(MavenBuilder.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.lambda$0(MavenBuilder.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:860)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.JavaCommandException: Command [[
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java -Xmx512M -Xss1024k -classpath 
....
]] failed with status 1
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.JavaCommand.execute(JavaCommand.java:327)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.compile(CompileMojo.java:578)

    ... 34 more
```

this is the stack of mvn clean install compilation

```
[INFO] --- vaadin-maven-plugin:7.7.6:compile (default) @ mle-webapp ---
[INFO] auto discovered modules [mleWidgeset.MLEWidgetset, mle.MLEWidgetset]
[INFO] Compiling module mleWidgeset.MLEWidgetset
[INFO]    [ERROR] Hint: Check that your module inherits 'com.google.gwt.core.Core' either directly or indirectly (
most often by inheriting module 'com.google.gwt.user.User')
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  02:44 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-08-02T12:01:00+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:7.7.6:compile (default) on project mle-webapp: Command [[
... long classpath here ...
[ERROR] ]] failed with status 1
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

this is the stack of command mvn package -X

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  26.507 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-08-02T12:08:12+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:7.7.6:compile (default) on project mle-webapp: Command [[
.... long class path here ...
[ERROR] ]] failed with status 1
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:7.7.6:compile (default) 
on project mle-webapp: Command [[
.... long class path here ...
]] failed with status 1
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:972)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:196)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Command [[
.... long class path here ...
]] failed with status 1
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.compile(CompileMojo.java:582)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.doExecute(CompileMojo.java:435)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.AbstractGwtShellMojo.execute(AbstractGwtShellMojo.java:182)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.JavaCommandException: Command [[
.... long class path here ...
]] failed with status 1
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.JavaCommand.execute(JavaCommand.java:327)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.compile(CompileMojo.java:578)
    ... 24 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

no more or different info with command mvn clean install -e -X

```
... long classpath ...
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\myPC\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.1.2.RELEASE\spring-expression-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\myPC\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.1.2.RELEASE\spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\myPC\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-websocket\5.1.2.RELEASE\spring-websocket-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\myPC\.m2\repository\org\vaadin\alump\notify\0.1.0-vaadin7\notify-0.1.0-vaadin7.jar
[DEBUG] GWT module mleWidgeset.MLEWidgetset found in C:\Users\myPC\mle-webapp\src\main\resources
[DEBUG] Module has an entrypoint
[DEBUG] Compilation not forced
[DEBUG] Execute command :
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java -Xmx512M -Xss1024k -classpath 
... long classpath ...
[INFO] Compiling module mleWidgeset.MLEWidgetset
[INFO]    [ERROR] Hint: Check that your module inherits 'com.google.gwt.core.Core' either directly or indirectly (most often by inheriting module 'com.google.gwt.user.User')
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 28.545 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-08-03T11:04:32+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 48M/174M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:7.7.6:compile (default) on project mle-webapp: Command [[
... long classpath ...
[ERROR] ]] failed with status 1
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:7.7.6:compile (default) on project mle-webapp: Command [[
... long classpath ...
]] failed with status 1
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Command [[
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java -Xmx512M -Xss1024k -classpath 
... long classpath ...
]] failed with status 1
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.compile(CompileMojo.java:582)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.doExecute(CompileMojo.java:435)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.AbstractGwtShellMojo.execute(AbstractGwtShellMojo.java:182)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.JavaCommandException: Command [[
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java -Xmx512M -Xss1024k -classpath 
... long classpath ...
]] failed with status 1
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.JavaCommand.execute(JavaCommand.java:327)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.compile(CompileMojo.java:578)
    ... 24 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Apache Maven 3.3.9 (.........; 2015-11-10T17:41:47+01:00)
Maven home: C:\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.3.9
Java version: 17.0.7, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17
Default locale: it_IT, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
[DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api
```